# Google map Check if polygon contains marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to draw a polygon and check if it contains a marker.

I used this github code https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon to add a new method to the polygon class. The code below is working but always shows "NO" in console even when I draw a polygon around the pin, any help why ?

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(e) {

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405);
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(getPolygonCoords());
    if (polygon.Contains(point)) {
        console.log('YES');
    } else {
        console.log('NO');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Full code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Map</title>
    <style>
        #map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var drawingManager;
        var selectedShape;
        var all_overlays = [];

        function setSelection(shape) {
            clearSelection();
            selectedShape = shape;
            shape.setEditable(true);
        }

        function clearSelection() {
            if (selectedShape) {
                selectedShape.setEditable(false);
                selectedShape = null;
            }
        }

        function getPolygonCoords() {
            var coordinates = new Array();
            if (!selectedShape) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var len = selectedShape.getPath().getLength();
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    coordinates.push(selectedShape.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5));
                }
                return coordinates;
            }
        }

        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                zoomControl: true
            });
            var polyOptions = {
                fillColor: '#0099FF',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                strokeColor: '#AA2143',
                strokeWeight: 2,
                editable: true
            };
            // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw Polygons
            drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
                    ]
                },
                polygonOptions: polyOptions,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains = function(point) {
                var crossings = 0,
                    path = this.getPath();

                // for each edge
                for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
                    var a = path.getAt(i),
                        j = i + 1;
                    if (j >= path.getLength()) {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    var b = path.getAt(j);
                    if (rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b)) {
                        crossings++;
                    }
                }

                // odd number of crossings?
                return (crossings % 2 == 1);

                function rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b) {
                    var px = point.lng(),
                        py = point.lat(),
                        ax = a.lng(),
                        ay = a.lat(),
                        bx = b.lng(),
                        by = b.lat();
                    if (ay > by) {
                        ax = b.lng();
                        ay = b.lat();
                        bx = a.lng();
                        by = a.lat();
                    }
                    // alter longitude to cater for 180 degree crossings
                    if (px < 0) {
                        px += 360;
                    }
                    if (ax < 0) {
                        ax += 360;
                    }
                    if (bx < 0) {
                        bx += 360;
                    }

                    if (py == ay || py == by) py += 0.00000001;
                    if ((py > by || py < ay) || (px > Math.max(ax, bx))) return false;
                    if (px < Math.min(ax, bx)) return true;

                    var red = (ax != bx) ? ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)) : Infinity;
                    var blue = (ax != px) ? ((py - ay) / (px - ax)) : Infinity;
                    return (blue >= red);

                }

            };
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(e) {

                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405);
                var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(getPolygonCoords());
                if (polygon.Contains(point)) {
                    console.log('YES');
                } else {
                    console.log('NO');
                }
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
                all_overlays.push(e);
                if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
                    // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
                    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

                    // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user mouses down on it.
                    var newShape = e.overlay;
                    newShape.type = e.type;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
                        setSelection(newShape);
                    });
                    setSelection(newShape);
                }
            });

            // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the map is clicked.
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: 33.619003,
                    lng: -83.867405
                },
                map: map
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `Contains` function seems to bear no relation to the `containsLatLng` function you said you're using.  Why not just use the `containsLocation` function that's built into the Google Maps' Geometry library?

Comment: I changed it to this var isWithinPolygon = polygon.containsLatLng(point); console.log(isWithinPolygon); but it shown an error in console : TypeError: polygon.containsLatLng is not a function

Comment: this is also not working :  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405);
                
                var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, getPolygonCoords());
                console.log(isWithinPolygon); gives an error

Comment: you need to add `geometry` to the list of libraries that you're loading in when you load the API JS.  Try `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing,geometry">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is :

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(getPolygonCoords());
```

the argument passed to the Polygon-constructor is not a valid [`PolygonOptions`-object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#PolygonOptions), so you create an empty polygon, without a path.

There is no need to create a polygon, there already existsa polygon(created via the DrawingManager)...just use it:

```js
function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                zoomControl: true
            });
            var polyOptions = {
                fillColor: '#0099FF',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                strokeColor: '#AA2143',
                strokeWeight: 2,
                editable: true
            };
            // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw Polygons
            drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                 drawingMode:google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
                    ]
                },
                polygonOptions: polyOptions,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Contains = function(point) {
                var crossings = 0,
                    path = this.getPath();
                    
                // for each edge
                for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
                    var a = path.getAt(i),
                        j = i + 1;
                    if (j >= path.getLength()) {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    var b = path.getAt(j);
                    if (rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b)) {
                        crossings++;
                    }
                }

                // odd number of crossings?
                return (crossings % 2 == 1);

                function rayCrossesSegment(point, a, b) { 
                    var px = point.lng(),
                        py = point.lat(),
                        ax = a.lng(),
                        ay = a.lat(),
                        bx = b.lng(),
                        by = b.lat();
                    if (ay > by) {
                        ax = b.lng();
                        ay = b.lat();
                        bx = a.lng();
                        by = a.lat();
                    }
                    // alter longitude to cater for 180 degree crossings
                    if (px < 0) {
                        px += 360;
                    }
                    if (ax < 0) {
                        ax += 360;
                    }
                    if (bx < 0) {
                        bx += 360;
                    }

                    if (py == ay || py == by) py += 0.00000001;
                    if ((py > by || py < ay) || (px > Math.max(ax, bx))) return false;
                    if (px < Math.min(ax, bx)) return true;

                    var red = (ax != bx) ? ((by - ay) / (bx - ax)) : Infinity;
                    var blue = (ax != px) ? ((py - ay) / (px - ax)) : Infinity;
                    return (blue >= red);

                }

            };
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {

                if (polygon.Contains(marker.getPosition())) {
                    alert('YES');
                } else {
                    alert('NO');
                }
            });
            
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: 33.619003,
                    lng: -83.867405
                },
                map: map
            });
        }
```

```css
#map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="map">
    </div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=drawing&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I had better upvote this if I'm going to use it in Production. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dr.Molle This is very useful but it doesn't seem to trigger the polygoncomplete event when we edit the polygon using the vertices. Is there any way to accomplish this? It'd be really helpful.